# is "the first night" an adverbial of time?

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

> [the other day](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/day?q=the%20next%20day): a few days ago:
>
> Didn't I see you in the post office the other day?
>
> [the other night](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/night): on one evening recently:
>
> I saw Naomi at the gym the other night.

My question is:

is "**the first night**" an adverbial of time?

Eg: [See This Conversation](http://www.talkenglish.com/conversation/practice/socializing)

> James: Are you ready for the business trip?
>
> Paul: Yeah. I'm a little nervous.
>
> James: Is this your first business trip?
>
> Paul: No. I just don't know any of these people. Do you have any
>   advice for me?
>
> James: Just socialize. Get to know them. Go out for drinks one night.
>
> Paul: Actually, two of our clients are taking me out for drinks **the
>   first night.**

**Note**: Please give a referenced source for your answer?

Comment: It is an adverbial of time, along with _"The second night"_,  _"The third night"_, _"The fourth night"_, ...

Comment: What makes you think that it isn't an adverbial of time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"**the first night**" can be either a [**noun**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/first-night) - *'the first public performance of a play'* or an *'adverbial of time'*.

As the [**Learn English British Council**](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/adverbials/adverbials-time) says:

We use adverbials of time to say:

1. when something happened.

   - I saw Mary **yesterday**.
   - I went to the park **two days ago**.
   - **Last night** we were at the cinema.
2. for how long.

   - We waited **all day**.
   - They have lived here **since 2004**.
3. how often (frequency).

   - They **usually** watched television in the evening.
   - We **sometimes** went to work by car.

> We often use a **noun phrase** as a time adverbial: